# Check if a byte string ends with a special character with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I am parsing a XML file which contains some UTF-8 encoded text with **Python 3.6**:

```
<line>
  <text>Some text which could end with ¬</text>
</line>
```

I am parsing it with `xml.etree.ElementTree` and I get the `text` element as an element:

```
<Element 'text' at 0x105577c78>
```

I can get the text string with

```
text_string = text.text.encode('utf-8')
msg = "Text string: {}".format(text_string)
self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(msg))
```

And I get:

```
Text string: b'Some text which could end with \xac'
```

Now I need to know if this string is ending with the **¬** character:

```
if text_string.endswith('¬'):
    print("The text ends which the char!")
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

If I change to `if text_string.endswith(b'¬'):` I get another error:

```
    if text_string.endswith(b'\xac'):
                           ^
SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
```

I understand I am confused because `text_string` is bytes and not string, but I cannot understand how I can solve my problem.

How I can convert bytes to string?
Or how I can search for a special character into a byte object?

Thanks!

Comment: `if text_string.endswith(b'\xac'):` - https://eval.in/931046

Comment: You should check strings with same encoding --- `if text_string.endswith('¬'.encode('utf-8')):`

Comment: *"All characters are special."* -- [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist)

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks!**

Both advises in comments work:

```
if text_string.endswith(b'\xac'):
if text_string.endswith('¬'.encode('utf-8')):
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7 the default is ASCII encoding if no other encoding hints are given. See this [PEP documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

So, if you are using Python 2.7 place the following comment at the top of your program script then everything should work.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

For Python 3.x the default is UTF-8 encoding so you need to change the following:

From:

```py
text_string = text.text.encode('utf-8')
```

To:

```py
text_string = text.text
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't they change that in Python 3 to default to UTF-8?

Comment: Mark Ransom, after a quick document search I think you are correct. Python 3.x seems to default to UTF-8. I will edit my comment above accordingly. Curious to know why original post did not work if it was in the 3.x version.

Comment: I think the error message was self-explanatory: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters. Now why non-ASCII isn't allowed, I don't know, seems like a pretty arbitrary decision to me.

Comment: Figured out why the original post did not work in 3.x. Since the encoding is already UTF-8 the encode function changes the variable from <class 'str'> to <class 'byte'>. Edited my post again to incorporate solution. Thanks for the spot check Mark Ransom, the result was a much better answer being produced.